# How do you create a scrolling window over a still background image with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question should be pretty easy for some of you CSS gurus. At least I hope it is. All I want to know is what the CSS looks like that accomplishes this effect:

http://www.nodeconf.com/

If you scroll that page you can see how they've created this "slits" which you can scroll to peer at different portions of a background image. Each slit seems to have a different image. I thought it was really cool but have no idea how to implement something similar. Does this effect require the use of JavaScript? If so, how complicated is it to do?

Comment: You're looking for **parallax scrolling**.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Will execute Google-fu immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the source I think it's more something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WZm9Z/

html:

```
<div class="image-block" style="background:url(http://placekitten.com/1543/1024) no-repeat center center fixed;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: @user3019837 who ever you are, nice answer. welcome to the community. a community of people trying to help. there is a social feed by the way.

Comment: Any particular reason why the background image was done as an inline style? Some clever trick I'm not aware of?

Comment: This is awesome, how would you add alt text to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kx3cP/

html:

```
<div class="background"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1800/950" alt=""></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.background { z-index: -9999; position:fixed; }
.content {background: black; width 50%; height:50em; margin:2em;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on the page and choose "inspect element" you will find that the CSS for those background images is:

```
  background: url(images/aBR9P1476.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

This is basically shorthand for:

```
  background-image:url(images/aBR9P1476.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
```

What you are interested in specifically is the last property "background-attachment".

See the documentation for this property here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

> The background-attachment property sets whether a
>   background image is fixed or scrolls with the rest of the page.

Cheers

Comment: Haha I appreciate it, but I wasn't confused by the fixed background. Rather the foreground creating a sort of transparency mask over the fixed background. Sorry if my question was confusing, I didn't really know what I was asking until someone said "parallax scrolling" in the comments.